# Making a box menu. How do I color/highlight the selection?

Tags: powershell, colors, menu, items

So I've pieced together a menu that contains a title and options you can select from. Selecting an item is done by using the arrow keys. I want to have the selected item highlighted so you can tell which item you are currently selecting. I'm new to PowerShell and am familiar as to how to change colors with write-host but in this example I am clueless. The line in question that I believe I need to inject the color options into is the one that starts with $Width. I'd really appreciate some insight! This is my last hiccup before beginning to add actual code!

```
    Function Create-Menu (){
    
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][String]$MenuTitle,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][array]$MenuOptions
    )

    $MaxValue = $MenuOptions.count-1
    $Selection = 0
    $EnterPressed = $False
    
    Clear-Host

    While($EnterPressed -eq $False){

        For ($i=0; $i -le $MaxValue; $i++){
            
    $Width = if($Title){$Length = $Title.Length;$Length2 = $MenuOptions|%{$_.length}|Sort -Descending|Select -First 1;$Length2,$Length|Sort -Descending|Select -First 1}else{$MenuOptions|%{$_.length}|Sort -Descending|Select -First 1}
    $Buffer = if(($Width*1.5) -gt 78){(78-$width)/2}else{$width/4}
    if($Buffer -gt 6){$Buffer = 6}
    $MaxWidth = $Buffer*2+$Width+$($MenuOptions.count).length
    $Menu = @()
    $Menu += "╔"+"═"*$maxwidth+"╗"
    if($MenuTitle){
        $Menu += "║"+" "*[Math]::Floor(($maxwidth-$MenuTitle.Length)/2)+$MenuTitle+" "*[Math]::Ceiling(($maxwidth-$MenuTitle.Length)/2)+"║"
        $Menu += "╟"+"─"*$maxwidth+"╢"
    }
    For($i=1;$i -le $MenuOptions.count;$i++){
        $Item = "$i`. "
        $Menu += "║"+" "*$Buffer+$Item+$MenuOptions[$i-1]+" "*($MaxWidth-$Buffer-$Item.Length-$MenuOptions[$i-1].Length)+"║"
    }
    $Menu += "╚"+"═"*$maxwidth+"╝"
    $menu
}

        $KeyInput = $host.ui.rawui.readkey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown").virtualkeycode

        Switch($KeyInput){
            13{
                $EnterPressed = $True
                $script:Selection = "$Selection"
                Clear-Host
                break
            }

            38{
                If ($Selection -eq 0){
                    $Selection = $MaxValue
                } Else {
                    $Selection -= 1
                }
                Clear-Host
                break
            }

            40{
                If ($Selection -eq $MaxValue){
                    $Selection = 0
                } Else {
                    $Selection +=1
                }
                Clear-Host
                break
            }
            Default{
                Clear-Host
            }
        }
    }
}

#MainMenu
Function MainMenu (){
Create-Menu -MenuTitle "Tool" -MenuOptions "Lookup","Prep","Tools","Settings","Cleanup and Exit"
If($script:Selection -eq 0) {Lookup}
If($script:Selection -eq 1) {PrepMenu} 
If($script:Selection -eq 2) {ToolsMenu} 
If($script:Selection -eq 3) {SettingsMenu} 
If($script:Selection -eq 4) {CleanupAndExit} 
}

MainMenu

pause
```

The code outputs the following:

```
╔═════════════════════════╗
║          Tool           ║
╟─────────────────────────╢
║    1. Lookup            ║
║    2. Prep              ║
║    3. Tools             ║
║    4. Settings          ║
║    5. Cleanup and Exit  ║
╚═════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: You should add a tag for powershell or nobody will find this.

Comment: Appreciate the advice. First post..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add color in (I used Green, but that's up to you) with some minor adjustments to your code:

```
function Create-Menu {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][String]$MenuTitle,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)][array]$MenuOptions
    )

    # test if we're not running in the ISE
    if ($Host.Name -match 'ISE') {
        Throw "This menu must be run in PowerShell Console"
    }

    $MaxValue = $MenuOptions.Count-1
    $Selection = 0
    $EnterPressed = $False

    While(!$EnterPressed) {
        # draw the menu
        Clear-Host
        for ($i = 0; $i -le $MaxValue; $i++){
            [int]$Width = [math]::Max($MenuTitle.Length, ($MenuOptions | Measure-Object -Property Length -Maximum).Maximum)
            [int]$Buffer = if (($Width * 1.5) -gt 78) { (78 - $width) / 2 } else { $width / 4 }
            $Buffer = [math]::Min(6, $Buffer)
            $MaxWidth = $Buffer * 2 + $Width + $MenuOptions.Count.ToString().Length
            Write-Host ("╔" + "═" * $maxwidth + "╗")
            # write the title if present
            if (!([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($MenuTitle))) {
                $leftSpace  = ' ' * [Math]::Floor(($maxwidth - $MenuTitle.Length)/2)
                $rightSpace = ' ' * [Math]::Ceiling(($maxwidth - $MenuTitle.Length)/2)
                Write-Host ("║" + $leftSpace + $MenuTitle + $rightSpace + "║")
                Write-Host ("╟" + "─" * $maxwidth + "╢")
            }
            # write the menu option lines
            for($i = 0; $i -lt $MenuOptions.Count; $i++){
                $Item = "$($i + 1). "
                $Option = $MenuOptions[$i]
                $leftSpace  = ' ' * $Buffer
                $rightSpace = ' ' * ($MaxWidth - $Buffer - $Item.Length - $Option.Length)
                $line = "║" + $leftSpace + $Item + $Option + $rightSpace + "║"
                if ($Selection -eq $i) {
                    Write-Host $line -ForegroundColor Green
                }
                else {
                    Write-Host $line
                }
            }
            Write-Host ("╚" + "═" * $maxwidth + "╝")
        }
        # wait for an accepted key press
        do {
            $KeyInput = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown').VirtualKeyCode
        } while (13, 38, 40 -notcontains $KeyInput)


        Switch($KeyInput){
            13{
                $EnterPressed = $True
                return $Selection
            }
            38 {
                $Selection--
                if ($Selection -lt 0){ $Selection = $MaxValue }
                break
            }
            40 { 
                $Selection++
                if ($Selection -gt $MaxValue) { $Selection = 0 }
                # or:    $Selection = ($Selection + 1) % ($MaxValue + 1)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

#MainMenu
function MainMenu {
    $selected = Create-Menu -MenuTitle "Tools" -MenuOptions "Lookup","Prep","Tools","Settings","Cleanup and Exit"
    switch ($selected) {
        0 {"Lookup"}
        1 {"PrepMenu"}
        2 {"ToolsMenu"}
        3 {"SettingsMenu"}
        4 {"CleanupAndExit"}
    }
}

MainMenu
```

---

**Edit**

Just for the fun of it, the above code uses `Clear-Host` before each redraw of the menu which results in a workable, but flickering menu.
Below the same menu, but this time it redraws without first clearing the console window resulting in a much smoother menu.

```
function Create-Menu {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)][string]  $MenuTitle = $null,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string[]]$MenuOptions
    )

    # test if we're not running in the ISE
    if ($Host.Name -match 'ISE') {
        Throw "This menu must be run in PowerShell Console"
    }

    $MaxValue = $MenuOptions.Count-1
    $Selection = 0
    $EnterPressed = $False
    [console]::CursorVisible = $false  # prevents cursor flickering
    Clear-Host

    while(!$EnterPressed) {
        # draw the menu without Clear-Host to prevent flicker
        [console]::SetCursorPosition(0,0)
        for ($i = 0; $i -le $MaxValue; $i++){
            [int]$Width = [math]::Max($MenuTitle.Length, ($MenuOptions | Measure-Object -Property Length -Maximum).Maximum)
            [int]$Buffer = if (($Width * 1.5) -gt 78) { (78 - $width) / 2 } else { $width / 4 }
            $Buffer = [math]::Min(6, $Buffer)
            $MaxWidth = $Buffer * 2 + $Width + $MenuOptions.Count.ToString().Length
            Write-Host ("╔" + "═" * $maxwidth + "╗")
            # write the title if present
            if (!([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($MenuTitle))) {
                $leftSpace  = ' ' * [Math]::Floor(($maxwidth - $MenuTitle.Length)/2)
                $rightSpace = ' ' * [Math]::Ceiling(($maxwidth - $MenuTitle.Length)/2)
                Write-Host ("║" + $leftSpace + $MenuTitle + $rightSpace + "║")
                Write-Host ("╟" + "─" * $maxwidth + "╢")
            }
            # write the menu option lines
            for($i = 0; $i -lt $MenuOptions.Count; $i++){
                $Item = "$($i + 1). "
                $Option = $MenuOptions[$i]
                $leftSpace  = ' ' * $Buffer
                $rightSpace = ' ' * ($MaxWidth - $Buffer - $Item.Length - $Option.Length)
                $line = "║" + $leftSpace + $Item + $Option + $rightSpace + "║"
                if ($Selection -eq $i) {
                    Write-Host $line -ForegroundColor Green
                }
                else {
                    Write-Host $line
                }
            }
            Write-Host ("╚" + "═" * $maxwidth + "╝")
        }
        # wait for an accepted key press
        do {
            $KeyInput = $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey('NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown').VirtualKeyCode
        } while (13, 38, 40 -notcontains $KeyInput)


        Switch($KeyInput){
            13{
                $EnterPressed = $True
                [console]::CursorVisible = $true  # reset the cursors visibility
                return $Selection
            }
            38 {
                $Selection--
                if ($Selection -lt 0){ $Selection = $MaxValue }
                break
            }
            40 { 
                $Selection++
                if ($Selection -gt $MaxValue) { $Selection = 0 }
                # or:    $Selection = ($Selection + 1) % ($MaxValue + 1)
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

#MainMenu
function MainMenu {
    $selected = Create-Menu -MenuTitle "Tools" -MenuOptions "Lookup","Prep","Tools","Settings","Cleanup and Exit"
    switch ($selected) {
        0 {"Lookup"}
        1 {"PrepMenu"}
        2 {"ToolsMenu"}
        3 {"SettingsMenu"}
        4 {"CleanupAndExit"}
    }
}

MainMenu
```

[image]